# Extracting shapefile with suburbs of a city from OSM

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap

I never downloaded shapefiles from OpenStreetMap before and now I am trying to download a shapefile of the city of Turin (Italy) with the suburbs polygons encoded in it. I know for sure that the information about suburbs is there in OSM (check [here](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=236425165)), but I could not manage in any way, using any tool, to download something different from the *circoscrizioni* areas, which are bigger. If I download the Turin shapefiles from, for example, websites like [bbbike](https://download.bbbike.org/osm/) I get the usual shapefiles (buldings/landuse/natural/points etc.) but the suburbs are nowhere to be found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: get the data from Geofabrik

Comment: could only get macro-regions for free. City-level information are only available by purchasing, I think.

Comment: A little older dataset but has Turin Italy https://www.nextzen.org/metro-extracts/index.html#turin_italy

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot find the data I need in those files either. If just there was a simple way to extract the info from OSM, I'd be good to go.

Comment: What about finding a source to download the data you need in OSM XML file format (or PBF as the compressed version) that should include really all data that are available from the OSM data server, and if that fits your need, convert data to shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

In OSM, you can see that the suburbs have a key/tag pair of place:suburb.

On [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/), you can use that key/tag pair to build a query, which can then be exported into various formats. Overpass does not export directly to shapefile, but a GeoJSON or KML can easily be converted.

You can use the **Wizard** on Overpass to build your query. It should spit out something like this:

```
[out:json];
(
  relation["place"="suburb"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

[This link](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/HG3) will run a query for the features you're interested in. Click **Export** in the top toolbar to choose a format.

[image: Overpass Turbo export]